# Which headerfile is used for LogTrace function in Objective-C

Tags: ios, objective-c

I want to know headerfile used for LogTrace function in Objective-C

Comment: What do you mean ????? please elaborate your question ??

Comment: We include <stdio.h> for printf() in C language. In same way, which header file i should include for LogTrace() in Objective-C?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not aware of any `LogTrace()` function in Objective-C, but you can use `NSLog()`, which is found in NSObjCRuntime.h. You don't usually need to explicitly include it in your source because it gets included by other headers that you already include from the Foundation.framework.

Answer (score 0):

Are you referring to this LogTrace : http://brenwill.com/2010/flexible-ios-logging/ ?

If so, the instruction suggests that you need to import Logging.h

```
#import "Logging.h"
```